# Remove Mac as possible destination for audio/video and likewise hide other machines not on network

Tags: macos, network, audio, video, big-sur

I'm sure most would have noticed destinations for video and audio in settings and other contexts also being other neighbouring machines, that are **not** on your Wi-fi network. I must assume my Mac shows up on these machines as well.

What service is making these discoveries and can it be controlled? With some difficulty if this is needed. What I want is:

1. disable my machine announcing itself for others, that are not on
   my network.
2. disable other machines showing up in any shape or form, that are not
   on my network.

In my case all sharing is off and my firewall is up.

Here's an example from Console where an Apple TV shows up as a possible destination for audio. Note that IDs have been replaced with "[XXYYZZ]".

```
preselection    15:25:56.738146+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    Ignoring device found non-cacheable: 4724156068875, 'Apple TV 4', 1d9/Wt5fFbwI
preselection    15:25:56.747423+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManager- routingManager_logDetailsOfEndpoints: The following endpoints are newly available for endpointManager=AirPlay
    [0] Endpoint=Apple TV 4, supportedFeatures=screen+audio+playback+music
preselection    15:25:58.569331+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManager_macOSAudio- FigRoutingManager_macOSAddEndpointToContext: Adding endpoint with name 'Apple TV 4' (groupable: NO) to context type: System Audio. Options: {
    clientPID = 559;
    clientRouteRequestID = "[XXYYZZ]";
}
preselection    15:25:58.569521+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManager- FigRoutingManagerLogRoutingRequestDetails: preprocessAddEndpoint - isWHAGroupable=NO endpoints=Apple TV 4, includeLocal=NO, clientRoutingContextType=System Audio, clientPID=559, clientName=ControlCenter, initiator=(null), avoidAuthPrompt=NO, silentSender=NO
preselection    15:25:58.570216+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManagerContextUtilities- FigRoutingManagerContextUtilities_AddCurrentlyActivatingEndpoint: context utilities: Add currently activating endpoint for endpointID=<private>, endpointName=Apple TV 4, contextType=System Audio
preselection    15:25:58.570393+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManager- FigRoutingManager_macOSActivateEndpoint: Activating endpoint 'Apple TV 4' with features 6
preselection    15:25:58.573559+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManager- FigRoutingManagerEndpointActivateWithCompletionCallback: routingManager: endpointName = Apple TV 4, inFeatures=6, inActivateOptions={
    HijackID = "[XXYYZZ]";
    PrimaryUsage = "PrimaryUsage_Playback";
    RoutingContextUUID = "[XXYYZZ]";
    clientPID = 559;
}
preselection    15:25:58.574146+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    Activating endpoint [0xF0F6] 'Apple TV 4' with features 0x6 and options {
    "HijackID" : "[XXYYZZ]",
    "clientPID" : 559,
    "RoutingContextUUID" : "[XXYYZZ]",
    "PrimaryUsage" : "PrimaryUsage_Playback",
}
preselection    15:25:58.583309+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0xF0F6] Activating endpoint 'Apple TV 4' (AppleTV5,3 v620.8.2) with seed 1...
preselection    15:25:58.591037+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0x9CBC] Connect over AWDL with "Apple TV 4" ( preferAWDL = 0, isInfraAvailable = 0, isAWDLAvailable = 1 )
preselection    15:25:58.595149+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    APTransportConnectionHTTP 0xD6DA with name Apple TV 4-ctrl created. Connection QoS: 0
preselection    15:25:58.595549+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    APTransportConnectionHTTP 0x6782 with name Apple TV 4-rctl created. Connection QoS: 0
preselection    15:25:58.595822+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    APTransportStream 0xE12D with name Apple TV 4-ctrl created.
preselection    15:25:58.603470+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    Reconfirming PTR for 044BEDA4F40B@Apple TV 4._raop._tcp.local. on awdl0
preselection    15:25:58.603494+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    Reconfirming PTR for Apple TV 4._airplay._tcp.local. on awdl0
preselection    15:25:58.658299+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0x9CBC] Disconnecting from 'Apple TV 4-AP'
preselection    15:25:58.658915+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0xF0F6] Deactivating endpoint 'Apple TV 4' with reason 'FailedActivation'...
preselection    15:25:58.658991+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManager- routingManager_macOSEndpointActivateCompletionCallback_block_invoke: routingManager_macOSEndpointHelpers: endpointName = Apple TV 4, inActivationSeed=1, err = 1, inFeatures=0
preselection    15:25:58.659519+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManagerContextUtilities- FigRoutingManagerContextUtilities_ResetCurrentlyActivatingEndpointInfo: context utilities: ResetCurrentlyActivatingEndpointInfo called for contextType=System Audio, endpointID=<private>, endpointName=Apple TV 4 reason=configUpdateReasonEndedFailed
preselection    15:25:58.662127+0200    AirPlayUIAgent  Prompt complete[0xB69E] {
    "finishedWithPromptInfo" : 
    {
        "ATVName" : "Apple TV 4",
        "savePassword" : false,
        "uniqueID" : "[XXYYZZ]",
        "MACAddress" : 044beda4 f40b                       |^K^^^^          | (6 bytes),
    },
}
preselection    15:25:58.662556+0200    AirPlayUIAgent  Cannot connect error for Apple TV 4
preselection    15:25:58.827135+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0xF0F6] endpoint_clearEndpointState id:[XXYYZZ]name:Apple TV 4
preselection    15:25:58.827189+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0xF0F6] Dissociating endpoint 'Apple TV 4'...
preselection    15:25:58.959250+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManager- routingManager_logDetailsOfEndpoints: The following endpoints went away for endpointManager=AirPlay
    [0] Endpoint=Apple TV 4, supportedFeatures=screen+audio+playback+music
preselection    15:26:58.661237+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0xF0F6] endpoint_clearEndpointState id:[XXYYZZ]name:Apple TV 4
preselection    15:28:59.797694+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    Ignoring device found non-cacheable: 4724156068875, 'Apple TV 4', 1d9/Wt5fFbwI
preselection    15:28:59.798666+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManager- routingManager_logDetailsOfEndpoints: The following endpoints are newly available for endpointManager=AirPlay
    [0] Endpoint=Apple TV 4, supportedFeatures=screen+audio+playback+music
preselection    15:29:08.657963+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    -FigRoutingManager- routingManager_logDetailsOfEndpoints: The following endpoints went away for endpointManager=AirPlay
    [0] Endpoint=Apple TV 4, supportedFeatures=screen+audio+playback+music
preselection    15:29:08.672410+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0xA5FC] endpoint_clearEndpointState id:[XXYYZZ] name:Apple TV 4
preselection    15:29:08.672646+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0xA5FC] Dissociating endpoint 'Apple TV 4'...
preselection    15:29:08.673079+0200    AirPlayXPCHelper    [0xA5FC] endpoint_clearEndpointState id:[XXYYZZ] name:Apple TV 4
```

Comment: I don't think it's usual for devices on other networks to appear on your Mac, nor vice versa. Can you give some examples of the devices listed?

Comment: Any Apple device or computer in the neighbourhood. It is **indeed** very typical and happens absolutely everywhere with any machine given there are other machines close-by (within 10 meters perhaps). It's not about networks at all. It's about how machines announce themselves to the surroundings and how they listen for these broadcasts from other machines. I want to stop both.

I've even talked to Apple about this and they have no advice as this seems to be by design. Services on macOS should be able to be controlled however. I'm not sure which service this concerns.